# email sending second mail not send

Tags: asp.net, smtp

When the text have value I send to email, and auto reply to user and I want send one for my self to get the content from `txtcontent` why the secound mail not send?

```
         if (txtMessagesubject.Text != "" && txtContent.Text != "")
           {

                   MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                   msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text));
                   msg.From = new MailAddress("TheDonkeySkin@gmail.com");

                   msg.Subject = txtMessagesubject.Text;
                   string body = "thx we are receive you contact";
                   msg.Body = body;
                   msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                   msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                   System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("TheDonkeySkin@gmail.com", "password");
                   smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                   smtp.Port = 587;
                   smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                   smtp.Credentials = myCredential;
                   smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                   try
                   {
                       smtp.Send(msg);
                       contactsupport.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;");
                       thankQ.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;");

                       txtEmail.Text = "";
                       txtMessagesubject.Text = "";
                       txtContent.Text = "";

                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       errorMsgReturn.Text = "Please try again";
                   }

                  /************************************/
                  MailMessage msgself = new MailMessage();
                  msgself.To.Add(new MailAddress("TheDonkeySkin@gmail.com"));
                  msgself.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
                  msgself.Subject = txtMessagesubject.Text;
                  string body2 = txtContent.Text;
                  msgself.Body = body2;
                  msgself.IsBodyHtml = true;
                  msgself.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                  SmtpClient smtpself = new SmtpClient();
                  System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredentialself = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("TheDonkeySkin@gmail.com", "password");
                  smtpself.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                  smtpself.Port = 587;
                  smtpself.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                  smtpself.Credentials = myCredentialself;
                  smtpself.EnableSsl = true;
                  try
                  {
                      smtpself.Send(msgself);
                  }
                  catch
                  {
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send first email you have :

```
txtEmail.Text = "";
```

and second

```
msgself.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
```

so

```
msgself.From = ""
```

Comment: ok now it work, but for second mail i send to my self i cant get who is sending

Comment: Delete  
  txtEmail.Text = "";     and add email of who is sending on subject for example >>  replace   msgself.Subject = txtMessagesubject.Text;   by   msgself.Subject = txtEmail.Text & " - " & txtMessagesubject.Text;

Comment: Subject = txtEmail.Text & " - " & txtMessagesubject.Text; wht mean? just copy this code replace? error show

Comment: u mean is msgself.Subject = txtEmail.Text +  " - " + txtMessagesubject.Text; ? is u mean?

Comment: see below image i want the msg i underline is to sender how to do?

Comment: i don't understand, if you just delete **txtEmail.Text = "";**    so    **msg.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);**   must contain the email adress that you would find on your  **FROM** receipt email